# MAX and CONVERT with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have made this:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT((numeroerba), INTEGER)) AS tot FROM cert_erba
```

I am trying to extract and convert a number from varchar to int but do not understand what is wrong.

No data return.

Comment: What *is* wrong? Are you getting an error?

Comment: no data return.

Comment: Maybe there's nothing in your database. This question is really hard to answer because it's really thin on details. For example: Sample data.

Comment: numeroerba is a VARCHAR. I have a lot of record in my db.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `CAST()` function, not `CONVERT()`.

```
SELECT MAX(CAST((numeroerba) AS SIGNED)) AS tot FROM cert_erba
```

`CONVERT()` is used for charset conversion.